# How to add transactions from Hyperledger Angular composer

Tags: angular, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I used Angular composer to auto-gen a frontend for my hyperledger, but I can only add Assets and participants.  How do I add a transactions button?

Comment: can you show your work?

Comment: all I did was use the basic auto-gen with my .bna @GautamRai, what do you need?

Comment: Composer currently has an issue https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3136 to add the transaction routes to the Angular generator. Just FYI.

Comment: is there a fix @PaulO'Mahony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:  Solution was to manually input the missing HTML from the (transactionName).component.HTML